# Аромат шампуня или аромат шампуней?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Чем отличаются - аромат шампуня и аромат шампуней - между собой? И есть ли ошибочное употребление варианта "аромат шампуней" в нейтральной / книжной лексике? Разговорной?..

Аромат шампуня - запах шампуня.

Аромат шампуней - запах шампуней. В таком случае ароматы шампуней должны быть похожи и сливаться между собой, образуя единый аромат? Или здесь какая-то другая логика?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146104/discussion-on-question-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: *ароматы шампуней должны быть похожи и сливаться между собой, образуя единый аромат* — аромат — это конкретный запах, это не смесь.

Answer (score 0):

**шампуня** - слово "*шампунь*" в родительном падеже, единственного числа

**шампуней** - слово "*шампунь*" в родительном падеже множественного числа.

Другими словами "*аромат шампуня*" - речь про аромат одного шампуня,
"*аромат шампуней*" - речь про аромат 2х и более шампуней.

Ошибочно употреблять "аромат шампуней" по отношению к одному шампуню.
Ошибочно употреблять "аромат шампуня" по отношению к нескольким шампуням.

Нет никакой разницы в нейтрально/книжной или разговорной лексике. Употребления падежей и других суффиксов слова образуются в соответсвии с правилами русского языка. В случае если случай не описан правилами, то обычно употребляют словарное написание данного слова (словосочетания).

Comment: "Аромат шампуней"? Не "ароматы шампуней"? Дело в том, что "запах шампуней" = "запах от шампуней". С ароматом так не работает.

Comment: Может быть и "аромат шампуней" и "ароматы шампуней". У нескольких шампуней может быть один и тот же аромат, все зависит от того что вы хотите донести до собеседника.

Comment: Ну тогда "шампуня", потому что шампунь — это вещество, а не бутылка.

Comment: Ну так может быть и не одно вещество, а несколько веществ.

Comment: Ну тогда несколько ароматов, пусть они и похожи. В словаре есть такой пример: *Ароматы весны.* Не аромат, потому что аромат — это конкретный запах, а не смесь.

Comment: У слова "весна" нет множетсвенного числа. У слова "шампунь" оно есть.

Comment: Я про то, почему не "аромат весны". Потому что аромат — это конкретный запах, а не смесь.

Comment: А почему у весны должна быть именно смесь запахов, а не один? Как по мне, такие вопросы правилами русского языка не регламентированы. Если у подлежащего слова есть множественное число и нет конкретного правила о конкретном словосочетании, то его можно употреблять в любом виде в словосочетаниях.

Comment: Потому что у весны нет конкретного запаха. Пахнут разные вещи, которые есть весной. Правила общие, никто не делал правила для конкретных словосочетаний. А у каждого слова своя история. Здесь словари помогают и анализ языка.

Comment: Каким образом вам поможет словарь здесь? Здесь не нужно толкование слова или его правописание, здесь разговор о том, что так тоже можно говорить и то не будет являеться ошибкой. Раве только словарь устойчивых выражений. Другое дело это фразиологизмы и другие устойчивые выражения. "Запах весны" это устойчивое выражение? Если да, тогда только так, если нет то и "Запахи весны" вполне может существовать.

Comment: Словарные примеры очень помогают. По ним можно сделать выводы. Мы говорили об аромате. А запах вполне может быть смесью.

Answer (score 0):

Разница в контексте.

1. В туалете стоит ароматизатор. При входе Вы почувствуете аромат шампун**я**.
2. В туалете нет ароматизатора, а каждый приходит со своим. При входе Вы почувствуете аромат шампун**ей**.
3. Отрывок из текста. Классификация аромат**ов** шампун**ей** основана на шкале Гиттенберга. (Фамилия вымышлена.)

В 3-ем контексте употребление словосочетания "аромат шампун**ей**" ошибочно.